# Why Is My React Static Web App failing to Deploy in Azure?

Tags: reactjs, azure, github, deployment

I am trying to create a Static Web App in Azure Portal and deploy React code written in Visual Studio Code from github.

The instructions I am following are here:

[Quickstart: Building your first static site with Azure Static Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/getting-started?tabs=react)

Steps:

1. Create Static Web App -> my-react-project

[image]

2. Select a Region -> East US 2

[image]

3. Choose build preset -> React

[image]

4. Enter location of app code -> /

[image]

5. Enter the location of the build output -> build

[image]

6. At this point I receive this message:

[image]

7. Then the build deploy fails:

   The content server has rejected the request with: BadRequest

   Reason: No matching Static Web App was found or the api key was invalid.

[image]

```
Run Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
with:
azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ***
repo_token: ***
action: upload
app_location: /
api_location: api
output_location: build
/usr/bin/docker run --name b469e5e693774fc22146d1ae8f22f864953d6a_86588a --label b469e5 --workdir /github/workspace --rm -e "INPUT_AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN" -e "INPUT_REPO_TOKEN" -e "INPUT_ACTION" -e "INPUT_APP_LOCATION" -e "INPUT_API_LOCATION" -e "INPUT_OUTPUT_LOCATION" -e "INPUT_API_BUILD_COMMAND" -e "INPUT_APP_ARTIFACT_LOCATION" -e "INPUT_APP_BUILD_COMMAND" -e "INPUT_ROUTES_LOCATION" -e "INPUT_SKIP_APP_BUILD" -e "INPUT_CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION" -e "INPUT_SKIP_API_BUILD" -e "INPUT_PRODUCTION_BRANCH" -e "INPUT_DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT" -e "INPUT_IS_STATIC_EXPORT" -e "INPUT_DATA_API_LOCATION" -e "HOME" -e "GITHUB_JOB" -e "GITHUB_REF" -e "GITHUB_SHA" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER_ID" -e "GITHUB_RUN_ID" -e "GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER" -e "GITHUB_RETENTION_DAYS" -e "GITHUB_RUN_ATTEMPT" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_ID" -e "GITHUB_ACTOR_ID" -e "GITHUB_ACTOR" -e "GITHUB_TRIGGERING_ACTOR" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW" -e "GITHUB_HEAD_REF" -e "GITHUB_BASE_REF" -e "GITHUB_EVENT_NAME" -e "GITHUB_SERVER_URL" -e "GITHUB_API_URL" -e "GITHUB_GRAPHQL_URL" -e "GITHUB_REF_NAME" -e "GITHUB_REF_PROTECTED" -e "GITHUB_REF_TYPE" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW_REF" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW_SHA" -e "GITHUB_WORKSPACE" -e "GITHUB_ACTION" -e "GITHUB_EVENT_PATH" -e "GITHUB_ACTION_REPOSITORY" -e "GITHUB_ACTION_REF" -e "GITHUB_PATH" -e "GITHUB_ENV" -e "GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY" -e "GITHUB_STATE" -e "GITHUB_OUTPUT" -e "RUNNER_OS" -e "RUNNER_ARCH" -e "RUNNER_NAME" -e "RUNNER_ENVIRONMENT" -e "RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE" -e "RUNNER_TEMP" -e "RUNNER_WORKSPACE" -e "ACTIONS_RUNTIME_URL" -e "ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN" -e "ACTIONS_CACHE_URL" -e "ACTIONS_RESULTS_URL" -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_runner_file_commands":"/github/file_commands" -v "/home/runner/work/my-react-project/my-react-project":"/github/workspace" b469e5:e693774fc22146d1ae8f22f864953d6a

DeploymentId: 04ac8c8e-306d-498e-890f-885b056fb322

Try to validate location at: '/github/workspace'.
App Directory Location: '/' was found.
Try to validate location at: '/github/workspace/swa-db-connections'.
Looking for event info
The content server has rejected the request with: BadRequest
Reason: No matching Static Web App was found or the api key was invalid.

For further information, please visit the Azure Static Web Apps documentation at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/
If you believe this behavior is unexpected, please raise a GitHub issue at https://github.com/azure/static-web-apps/issues/
Exiting
```

The repo is here:

[REPO](https://github.com/drdexter33/my-react-project)

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: Your repo is not visible, it's showing a 404 error. Can you re-share it?

Comment: Can you share the error in text format?

Comment: Updated repo link and added  error in text format @Dasari

Comment: Add the [Deployment token](https://i.imgur.com/dzau4fi.png) in GitHub workflow secret.

Comment: There are 2 options for adding secrets in github.  One is a repository secret and one is an environment secret

Comment: Also, there are around 20 workflows in my repo.  It seems that one is created each time the deployment failed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257118/discussion-between-tikhon-and-dasari-kamali).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Dasari Kamali for his assistance.

I was able to finally get this to work by doing the following:

1. Deleted old repo in github
2. Created new React project
3. Created new Static App in Azure
4. Code deployed this time with no errors

Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

*I changed your **App.js** file as follows and successfully deployed it to the Azure Static Web App.*

**Code :**

***App.js :***

```js
import React from 'react'; // Remove {useState} from this import
import GoalList from './components/GoalList';
import Header from './components/Header';
import logo from './logo2.svg';
import './App.css';

const ShowGoals = () => {
  const [showGoals, setShowGoals] = React.useState(false); // Use React.useState instead of useState
  const onClick = () => setShowGoals(true);
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="submit" value="Goals" onClick={onClick}></input>
      {showGoals ? <Goals /> : null}
    </div>
  );
}

const Goals = () => (
  <div id="goals">
    <Header />
    <GoalList />
  </div>
)

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <body>
          <p className='smaller'>
            Hello, My name is Doug Dexter and I am looking for my next opportunity as a web developer.
            <hr />
            I am currently learning full-stack development 
            using React and ASP.Net Core API.
            <hr />
            This website is written in React.
            <hr />
            <ShowGoals />
          </p>
        </body>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

***GitHub Workflow :***

```yaml
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true
          lfs: false
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_GENTLE_FLOWER_06B90A80F }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          action: "upload"
          app_location: "/" 
          api_location: "api" 
          output_location: "build" 

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_GENTLE_FLOWER_06B90A80F }}
          action: "close"
```

**Azure Static Web App Output :**

[image]